# Deploy Docker container to digital ocean nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a docker container that I am trying to deploy to a digital ocean droplet. Everything is set to go: the container, the nginx server, the digital ocean droplet, my domain with the correct records, etc. How do I actually make the connection from the nginx server to the container?

Comment: Is NGINX also containerized?

Comment: Nope just the application

Comment: In this case NGINX runs on the host so you should be able to connect via the port the container exposes using `localhost:8888` for example. If NGINX runs on a container then it shares the network with other containers so you can use the container name (ie `http://app_container_name:8888`).
Either case the nginx.conf needs to be configured setting `proxy_pass`